# T-SQL: COUNT does not count properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I need to perform the following query inside of a SQL function, in SQL Server 2008.

Note: @ncuota, @ccod, @cfecha and @rut are the arguments of the function, set to the proper variable types.

```
DECLARE @cpagos int
SELECT @cpagos = COUNT(Pago_NPago)
FROM Pago_Costa AS p INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Cancela_NPago, Cancela_TipoPago
FROM Cancela_Costa AS cc INNER JOIN Cuota_Costa AS cuota
ON Cancela_ConcCod = Cuota_ConcCod AND Cancela_ConcFecha = Cuota_ConcFecha
WHERE Cuota_NCuota = @ncuota AND Cancela_ConcCod = @ccod AND Cancela_ConcFecha = @cfecha
) AS c
ON c.Cancela_NPago=p.Pago_NPago AND c.Cancela_TipoPago = p.Pago_TipoPago
WHERE Pago_AlumnoRut = @rut
GROUP BY Pago_AlumnoRut
```

However, @cpagos gets either a NULL value (if I use GROUP BY) or 0 (if I don't), but if I execute the query as a regular query and not inside the function, it works properly and returns the value 2. What is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

TABLE DEFINITIONS:

```
Pago_Costa:
- Pago_NPago PK bigint
- Pago_TipoPago PK bit
- Pago_AlumnoRut FK nvarchar(9)
- Pago_Monto bigint
- Pago_FPago date
- Pago_TipoDoc smallint
- Pago_RefBoleta FK bigint
- Pago_RefTipoPago FK bit
- Pago_Obs nvarchar(200)

Cuota_Costa
- Cuota_NCuota PK smallint
- Cuota_ConcCod FK PK smallint
- Cuota_ConcFecha PK FK int
- Cuota_Valor biging

Cancela_Costa
- Cancela_NPago PK FK bigint
- Cancela_TipoPago PK FK bit
- Cancela_NCuota PK FK smallint
- Cancela_ConcCod PK FK smallint
- Cancela_ConcFecha PK FK int
- Cancela_Monto bigint
- Cancela_Cheque FK nvarchar(20)
```

FUNCTION. I'll be using a modified version of the function that I'm using to test the query.

```
FUNCTION verificaPagoCuotas
(
@rut nvarchar,
@ncuota smallint,
@ccod smallint,
@cfecha int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @cpagos int, @valor bigint
-- @valor is the real variable to be returned, but right now we're testing so it'll be @cpagos
SET @cpagos = (SELECT COUNT(Pago_NPago)
FROM Pago_Costa AS p INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Cancela_NPago, Cancela_TipoPago
FROM Cancela_Costa AS cc INNER JOIN Cuota_Costa AS cuota
ON Cancela_ConcCod = Cuota_ConcCod AND Cancela_ConcFecha = Cuota_ConcFecha AND Cancela_NCuota = Cuota_NCuota
WHERE Cancela_NCuota = @ncuota AND Cancela_ConcCod = @ccod AND Cancela_ConcFecha = @cfecha
) AS c
ON c.Cancela_NPago=p.Pago_NPago AND c.Cancela_TipoPago = p.Pago_TipoPago
WHERE Pago_AlumnoRut = @rut
RETURN @cpagos
... -- More irrelevant code
END
```

Comment: What is the value of `@rut` Is it possible that it is `NULL` (and/or not being passed properly)?

Comment: @rut in PHP is a string (I'm using bind variables though), and in SQL it's nvarchar.

Comment: @carlos Can you please post the php code? seems odd.

Comment: I don't know if it's neccesary, since I'm also executing this function under T-SQL, with fixed arguments, and I still get wrong return values.

Comment: @carlos It could be one of the other arguments `@ncuota @ccod & @cfecha`. Note: remove the `GROUP BY` since you are filtering for a single `Pago_AlumnoRut`.

Comment: Yep, I removed the GROUP BY statement and, instead of a NULL value, I get a 0. When I execute that query outside the function with the same arguments, I get a 2 instead.

Comment: Can you please post the table definitions?

Comment: As in, the CREATE TABLE statements with the respective fields?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I was fixing it...

Comment: I do not understand the column names, but to me it looks like `Cuota_Costa` has a composite primary key on `Cuota_NCuota, Cuota_ConcCod, Cuota_ConcFecha)` However in your query you are only joining on the last 2 columns.

Comment: That's correct! let me fix it.

Comment: I get the same error. When I execute the query outside the function the return value is 2, but inside of it it's 0 (returning @cpagos, that is).

Comment: There is nothing that would cause the query to execute differently in a function than outside. What matters is the data and the parameters passed. Can you provide some sample inputs that should not produce a null for @cpagaos but do anyway?

Comment: @carlos When you execute the query outside the function, try declaring & using the same variable names and types as in the function.

Comment: Using values theirselves, @rut = '21692464', @ncuota = 1, @ccod = 1, @cfecha = 2011. This produces the value 2. @Scrum, I tried before and it somehow doesn't like that I use declare and stuff outside the function.

Comment: Can you show us how you are declaring & calling the function? Does the function return a value or a table?

Comment: I'll do that right away.

Comment: What values are you testing with? Is it possible 1 of them is `null` or out of the `smallint` range?

Comment: That's it. @rut is set at the value 2, not the one it should have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to narrow down the problem. First, you should use `Set` instead of `Select`. `Set` will throw an error if more than one row is returned whereas Select will not. This is why including the Group By did not throw an error when it was added even though it should. I would exclude the Group By.

Now, iterations to try:

1. <strike>What is the count when use `Count(*)` instead of `Count(Pago_Npago)`?</strike>
2. What is the count when you only use the inner join?
3. What is the count when you exclude `Where Pago_Alumnorut = @Rut`
4. What is the count when you change the Inner Join to a Left Join and change the count to `Count(Cancela_NPago)`?

> > When you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

If you run the query directly in SSMS and using the function using identical parameters, and the results are different, then query in the function must be different than the one you ran in SSMS.

Comment: Point 2. What do you mean with just using the inner join?

Comment: @Carlos - Using only your derived table in your query. You have given it a table alias of `c`.

Comment: @Carlos - I see from your spec that Page_NPago is the PK so it should return the same result as Count(*). So you can skip test #1.

Comment: 1: 2 outside, 0 inside. 2: 2 outside, 2 inside. 3: 2 outside, 2 inside (but I run the risk of counting every person instead of just one, the RUT is the person's ID). 4: 2 outside, 0 inside.

Comment: So... Do I just use your second suggestion, or at least give it a try?

Comment: If test #1 produced different results from running inside the query vs. without, then barring the data changing between iterations, something in the function's query must be different. In short, given test #4, the direct query is finding two rows via the derived table that the function is not. You are absolutely sure you are running these against the same database and server with identical parameters that the direct query is literally a copy paste from the function?

Comment: Ah. The reason I'm using the join with Pago_Costa is because I need to identify the payments (pago) paid (cancela) by certain people (using the rut) and that pay certain fees (cuota).

Comment: Yes, I'm completely sure. I'm calling the function using a query with certain parameters, and the query is being executed outside the function with the same parameters in the places where they should be.

Comment: @Carlos - The join per se isn't the issue as much as the confusing discrepancy between the function result and the direct query result.  There are only three causes for that: 1. the query is different, 2. the data is different, 3. the data is changing between iterations. Assuming we rule out #3, I would absolutely verify that database and server are identical in every respect and that the queries are identical in every respect.

Comment: I'm working directly on the server and on the same database. There's just one of this database and one of these tables....

Comment: @Carlos - Then that would imply that the function query and the direct query are different. There is nothing else in the function other than the query and neither the function nor the direct query explicitly reference a database (e.g. DbName.dbo.TableName) and both are executed in the same query script against the same database and literally the same declare parameters to compare their results?

Comment: I found out something. I finally could execute the script outside the function, using variables. What's surprising is that I get the 0 value this way.

Comment: @Carlos - The real question is whether that is the same value you get when you execute the function in the same script using the same parameters against the same database. If so, then you have at least solved one issue which is the discrepancy between the script and the function. A second question is adjusting the query (as there should only be one now) to ensure you get the value you expect.

Comment: @Thomas Well, I did the following. I'm testing this outside the function. I executed the query, using the values inside the query. The value thrown by count was 2. Then, I replaced the values by variables, and before the query, I assigned to each of these variables their respective value. The value thrown by count was 0. So I believe this isn't related to the function anymore but the query itself, and somehow it behaves differently when I use variables instead of fixed values.

Comment: Thomas +1 Kudos for the continues help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is too simple. My problem is that I declared just "nvarchar", but I didn't specify the length. When I changed to nvarchar(8), the problem fixed automatically. Thank you for your enormous help!